# Hide gutter from Syntastic

Tags: vim, syntastic

Using the syntax checker Syntastic calls up a gutter which points to all lines with errors in it. Once I am done checking I would like to hide this gutter. The only way I have found is to reopen the same file. I must be missing something, how do I hide the gutter? I have tried `:set foldcolumn=0` to no avail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are called signs (`:h sign`). Try

```
:sign unplace *
```

Answer (score 4):

If you only want Syntastic's gutter to go away, use `:SyntasticReset`.

Answer (score 3):

You have 3 (that i know of :) side-columns in VIM. Fold, number and sign.

Gutter uses the sign one.

`:set signcolumn=auto` which should be the default and it will only show when gutter has content there. Set to `on|off` to show|hide.

Comment: Please add at least one sentence to explain why it works.

Comment: In VIM 8.2 I used `:set signcolumn=no`.